# Bounded Index of Nilpotency of $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is called with bounded index (of nilpotency) $n$ if $n$ is the smallest natural number such that $a^n=0$ for all nilpotent $a \in R$.
Now let $R$ be a commutatitve ring with bounded index $n$. how can I show that $R[x]$ is also with bounded index $m$, where $m \leq 1+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ? Probably it was proved by A. A. Klein. But I am unable to collect that paper. Please help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

(I would have made this a comment, but I don't yet have the 50 reps needed.)  You can find Klein's 4 page paper by googling "Abraham Klein bounded index nilpotence" and clicking the first link (which should be [given by this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sz0j3HUhukoC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=abraham%20klein%20bounded%20index%20nilpotence&source=bl&ots=RR0uLYDCuR&sig=zubTxgZJPHGivwyIoRtzt9ehVLU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TiJoVO_XNYqXyQTSlYKoDw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=abraham%20klein%20bounded%20index%20nilpotence&f=false) to a google book).

The result you want is theorem 4 in his paper "Rings with bounded index of nilpotence".